# Pure Javascript Modal does not show on synchronous process

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, modal-dialog, popup, ecmascript-5

I have a business requirement to show a waiting modal before calling a synchronous web API call.

I'm using very old code (before 2011 if I'm not mistaken) and I fear I am having trouble understanding why it doesn't work.
**We are not using ES6+**
This is the code to show the modal:

```
showWaitingMessage: function (isShow, title, message) {
        if (isShow) {
            var left = (window.top.$(document.body).width() / 2) - 150 + "px";
            div = $("<div></div>");
            div.attr("id", "messageDiv");
            div.attr("align", "center");
            div.css("width", "300px");
            div.css("border", "1px solid #000000");
            div.css("background", "#F7F3F7");
            div.css("z-index", "2000");
            div.css("position", "absolute");
            div.css("left", left);
            var html = "";
            if (title != undefined && title != null && title != "")
                html += "<div style='font-family:Tahoma,Arial;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;padding:10px 10px 0px 10px'>" + title + "</div>";
            html += "<div style='padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;'><img alt='' src='/_imgs/AdvFind/progress.gif'/></div>";
            if (message != undefined && message != null && message != "")
                html += "<div style='font-family:Tahoma,Arial;font-size:12px;padding:0px 10px 10px 10px'>" + message + "</div>";
            div.html(html);
            var top = (window.top.$(document.body).height() / 2) - (div.height() / 2);
            div.css({ "top": top });
            Elad.Global.greyout(true);
            window.top.document.body.appendChild(div[0]);
        }
        else {
            var div = window.top.$("#messageDiv");
            if (div.length > 0)
                div.remove();
            Elad.Global.greyout(false);
        }
    },
```

Here is where I'm trying to execute the above function:

```
 function createReminder() {
    if (shouldCreateReminder()) {

        Elad.Global.showWaitingMessage(true, "אנא המתן...", "אנא המתן ליצירת פעילות המשך עוקבת");

       // logic

            var result = Elad.Global.callWebApi("POST", url, request, null, createReminderErrorCallback);
            Elad.Global.showWaitingMessage(false);

            if (result && result.Success) {
             // logic
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, running the second part in a asynchronous way does seem to make the modal appear, so I'm perplexed by what's going on here.

Thank you!

Comment: show the modal, then make the sync call behind a 1ms setTimeout, giving time for the dom to show the modal before locking further rendering whilst waiting for the call to complete.

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm!
So what happened was that the DOM waits for the code to finish executing the synchronous code, and only then updated the DOM?
does this apply to all JS? dom updates are "awaited" for the code to finish executing?